# what is local scope exactly?

Tags: ruby, scope

To be honest, I still confused about the instance variable and local variable, not sure which should be used.

only one condition I know about local variable that can't be used is:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    local_var = 1
    @instance_var = 1
  end

  def show_local_var
   local_var
  end

  def show_instance_var
   @instance_var
  end
end
```

apparently, `MyClass.new.show_instance_var` works while `MyClass.new_show_local_var` not

the other thing about the two kind of variables is that the block seems share the same local scope, so the local variable can be referenced:

```
local_var = 1

3.times do
  puts local_var
end
```

There are all I know about the distinctions, is there any other  available? please let me know

if there is any articles about this, that would be so helpful for me,

Comment: I don't know ruby, but you seem to have the idea. A block is like a room in a factory. If you're in a chair factory, there's a `finishing` room-- the chair goes in unpainted and comes out painted. If a worker in *another* room says "hand me the paintbrush", the answer is "What? you mean the paintbrush from the `finishing` room? That's not here, it's not ours, it's probably been thrown away by now."

Comment: @Beta: Isn't the relation with blocks/closures more like: Somebody puts the paintbrush on the chair *before* it goes into the finishing room. Then inside the finishing room, the worker asks for a paintbrush and you tell him: "Yeah, we have none of our own paintbrushes here, but look, somebody had been kind enough to provide us with one from the outside"? Anyway it's the weirdest analogy I ever heard to describe the phenomenon, but I like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A local variable is used "right here right now" and can't be accessed from anywhere else.

```
class MyClass
  def foo
    local_var = 2
    #I use this to do some sort of calculation
    @instance_var = local_var + 34
    local_var = 5 * @instance_var
    puts local_var
  end
  # From here, local_var is unaccessible.
end
```

Once you're out of scope (`foo`'s `end` is passed) `local_var` is no more and can't be referred to.

The instance variable is available to the whole class at all times.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @instance_var = 0
  end

  def foo
    local_var = 2
    #I use this to do some sort of calculation
    @instance_var = local_var + 34
  end

  def some_operation
    if @instance_var == 36
      @instance_var = 3
    else
      @instance_var = 1
    end
  end
end
```

So when you call `m = MyClass.new` and later on `m.some_operation`, it's working with the same `@instance_var` .

And while we're at it, there are also Class variables (defined `@@class_var`) that are accessible from *any* instance of the class.

I don't have an article in particular to provide you, but some googling about `ruby variable scope` and about each type of variable independently should provide you with all the information you need!

Comment: Thank for your example, it starts to make sense to me, I should do more thinking to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

The second example you describe is called a [Closure](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb). Paul puts it quite nicely there:

> A closure is a block of code which meets three criteria:
>
> - It can be passed around as a value and
> - executed on demand by anyone who has that value, at which time
> - it can refer to variables from the context in which it was created (i.e. it is closed with respect to variable access, in the mathematical sense of the word "closed").

For a nice, quick introduction about the available scopes in Ruby you may refer to the [Ruby Programming wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Scope).

There is

- Local Scope
- Global Scope
- Instance Scope
- Class Scope

The "Default Scope", as it is sometimes referred to when executing code with no scope modifiers surrounding it, as in

```
@iv = "Who do I belong to?"
```

is the scope of the 'main' object.

Answer (score 1):

Local scope is limited to the location in which the variable is declared, i.e. a function, or a for loop, but cannot be accessed from outside that location. However, if you nest other constructs within the function, for loop, etc. then the inner constructs *can* access the local variable. Instance variables are scoped to the instance of the class.

[Article on ruby variable scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope)

[Article on scope in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29)