# Ruby metaprogramming: Initialize singleton_class variable

Tags: ruby, singleton, initialization, var

- Why does `Foo.val` return `nil` instead of `"foo"` before calling `Foo.set`?
- Is there any mechanism for initializing `@val` on class evaluation?
- In which scope is `@val  = "foo"` stored into?

  ```
  class Foo
    class << self
      @val  = "foo"
      attr_reader :val

      def set(val)
        @val = val
      end
    end
  end

  p Foo.val # nil
  Foo.set("bar")
  p Foo.val # "bar"
  ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can initialize `@val` in Foo like this:

```
class Foo
  @val  = "foo"
  class << self
    attr_reader :val

    def set(val)
      @val = val
    end
  end
end

p Foo.val         #=> "foo"
Foo.set("bar")
p Foo.val         #=> "bar"
```

Your code initializes `@val` not on Foo, but on Foo's metaclass

Answer (score 3):

Ruby generally executes expressions upon parsing them. The reason why your code did not perform as expected is because you are setting a class instance variable for the *singleton class* of Foo, but on the other hand you are accessing the class instance variable of Foo itself, that's why it doesn't work:

```
class << self
  @val  = "foo" # scope is class scope of singleton class of Foo
  attr_reader :val

  def set(val)
    # scope is instance scope of singleton class of Foo (equal to Foo itself)
    @val = val 
  end
end
```

That's why `Foo.val` yields `nil` in your case - it hasn't been set yet.

Setting `val` on class evaluation can be achieved in the way that Victor already demonstrated.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966793/what-is-local-scope-exactly/6966912#6966912) for a discussion about scope.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use #set.
Simply define #val method and use nil guard:

```
class Foo
    class << self
        def val; @val ||= "bar" end
    end
end
p Foo.val  #=> "bar"
```