# Initializing instance variables inside << self blocks

Tags: ruby

Specifically, why does the following code output `nil` instead of `1`?

```
class Foo
  class << self
    @bar = 1
    def bar
      @bar
    end
  end
end
p Foo.bar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby metaprogramming: Initialize singleton\_class variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968333/ruby-metaprogramming-initialize-singleton-class-variable)

Comment: Instance variables being `nil` seems fairly intuitive to me, considering you do not create an *instance* of Foo. Using class variables (i.e., `@@bar`) it works fine. Well, never mind. In a normal class the instance variable can indeed be set like you more or less try in the Eigenclass: `class A;@a=1;def self.a;@a;end;end;p A.a` This would print 1 just fine, without creating an instance of A.

Comment: ya, it's a dupe, I just didn't see the original when I searched, thanks! the title is not intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

In the `<< self` block, `self` is an instance of `#<Class:Foo>`.

```
class Foo
  puts "self in Foo declaration is: #{self} #{self.class} #{self.object_id}"
  class << self 
    @bar = 1
    puts "self in Foo.self declaration is: #{self} #{self.class} #{self.object_id}"
    def bar
      puts "self in class method is #{self} #{self.class} #{self.object_id}"
      @bar
    end
  end
end
p Foo.bar
```

This code outputs:

```
self in Foo declaration is: Foo Class 69910818825400
self in Foo.self declaration is: #<Class:Foo> Class 69910818825380
self in class method is Foo Class 69910818825400
```

So a slight modification to your code, that works as expected, is:

`class Foo
  @bar = 1
  class << self
    def bar
      @bar
    end
  end
end
p Foo.bar`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're modifying the Class definition of Foo with self you are still setting an instance variable which is not available through class scope.

If you want to have a class variable do it like.

```
class Foo
  class << self
    @@bar = 1
    def bar
     @@bar
    end
  end
end
p Foo.bar # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way different from:

```
class Foo
  @bar = 1

  def bar; @bar end
end
```

Instance variables belong to objects and are always looked up on `self`. `bar` is an instance method, so the `@bar` inside `bar` belongs to some instance of `Foo` (`self` is the receiver of `bar` at that point). The `@bar` at the beginning belongs to the class itself (`self` is `Foo` at that point).

Those are simply two completely different objects. The two ´@bar`s are completely unrelated.

In *your* example: the first `@bar` belongs to the singleton class of `Foo`, the second `@bar` belongs to the instance of the singleton class of `Foo` (i.e. `Foo`).

Here's how you could make it work:

```
class Foo
  @bar = 1

  def self.bar; @bar end
end
```